# Sort an array of small integers

Tags: algorithm, sorting

How can I sort an array of small integers in less than O(nlogn) knowing that all the integers can fit in only one bite and I have infinite memory to use?

Comment: [Counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: Or [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If input is bounded to lets say your specification (1 byte) and you have infinite memory, you can use this advantage to sort not based on comparions. One such algorithm is the **Key-indexed counting** with the complexity of O(n). Refer to this [explanation](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/demo/51DemoKeyIndexedCounting.pdf) for the detailed guide how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you had infinite hardware acting in zero time on a finite, but unknown number of small integers then you could create an array of logic units `f` that perform:

```
define f(x, y):
    return (x, y) if x <= y else (y, x)
```

The arrayed connections of these functional units whould produce its input in sorted order at the outputs of the last row, in zero time!

It's fun to *sometimes* think of having infinite resources acting in zero time :-)

Answer (score 0):

An example implementation in C++

(totally untested code)

```cpp
void SmallSort(std::vector<unsigned char>& small) {
  std::array<int, 256> counter;
  counter.fill(0);
  for(auto i : small) {
    ++counter[i];
  }

  // fill the array
  int idx = 0;
  auto cur = small.begin();
  for(auto i : counter) {
    next = cur + i;
    fill(cur, next, idx++);
    cur = next;
  }
}
```